# Overriding static methods

Tags: python, egg

I have to override a function on this egg [dicttoxml](https://github.com/quandyfactory/dicttoxml/blob/master/dicttoxml.py) however the problem is that not being a class I don't know how to override just a particular function.

I tried by creating a new "package" and importing * and then writing out the function I wanted to override but it's ignoring it all together, I'm not sure how or if it can be done.

Edit:
This a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mmarignoli/7e445841061bb366b7e2) to the code I changed the function is the same just changed item with segment

Edit2: I also added the way I import from the the other file, I called the new "package" dicttoxml_fast

Comment: The solution you tried should work, add more details (show some code).

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski I added a gist now

Answer (score 0):

this :

```
`from libs.dicttoxml_fast.dicttoxml_fast import dicttoxml`
```

cannot work with your current `dicttoxml_fast` module. You can import this way instead:

```
`from libs.dicttoxml_fast import dicttoxml_fast as dicttoxml`
```

but this will not make other functions from the original `dicttoxml` use your own version of `convert_list`. If that was your plan, you'll have to either fork the original (FWIW the author might be interested in your own implementation if it's strictly equivalent and faster) or monkeypatch it:

```
# dicttoxml_fast.py

import dicttoxml
from dicttoxml import *

def convert_list(items, ids, parent, attr_type):
    # your code here

# apply the monkeypatch
dicttoxml.convert_list = convert_list
```

then use `from libs.dicttoxml_fast.dicttoxml_fast import dicttoxml` in your client code.

Comment: My biggest problem is not so much not being able to call the function directly, is that one of the functions in the egg "convert" itself calls "convert_list" but it seems to call the one within the egg rather than the one I created, I think I might just use lxml and save time however

Comment: Have you tried the monkeypatch solution ? It should make `dicttoxml`'s functions use your own version of `convert_list` (as long as you do import `dicttoxml_fast` before calling on any `dicttoxml` function).